# htaccess - Redirect all traffic into subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all traffic to subdirectory so request like those:

a) http://localhost/app/index.php/app/ctrl
b) http://localhost/app/media/image.jpg

will be redirected (invisibly for user) to:

a) http://localhost/app/public/index.php/app/ctrl
b) http://localhost/app/public/media/image.jpg

As you can see my app is not directly in root directory, but also in subdirectory.

Here is my file structure:

```
/
    app/
        public/
            media/
               image.jpg
            index.php
        source/
        .htaccess

    otherapp/
```

I'm working in /app/.htaccess
IMO code below should work, unfortunately I get 404 not found

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)% "public/$1"
```

access.log:

```
::1 - - [21/Mar/2017:15:23:21 +0100] "GET /app/index.php/app/ctrl HTTP/1.1" 200 6681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"    
::1 - - [21/Mar/2017:15:23:30 +0100] "GET /app/media/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `app/.htaccess` use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!public/).*$ public/$0 [L,NC]
```

`(?!public/)` is negative lookahead to check if URI is already not stating with `/app/public/`

Comment: Perfect :) I completely forgot about redirect loop in my solution.